# Circular graph diagram with ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph

I'm writing for a suggestion. I would like to produce the graph in the image that I attached with `ggplot` or some other R package. I tried with `ggplot` and `igraph` but it did not work. I have and adjacency matrix with many zeros and where the connectivity values go from -1 to 1. The matrix has the row and column labels. It is an undirected graph. I transformed the matrix into a graph with the `igraph` package, however when I tried to plot it with `ggraph`, with the option dendrogram circular, I receive an error message advising me that I should use a directed graph. I tried also to use a chord plot, but it is not useful in my case. What should I do to produce with R the image that I attached, starting from an undirected adjacency matrix?

[image: circular graph]

Comment: check this? https://www.jessesadler.com/post/network-analysis-with-r/ and maybe this too: https://r-graph-gallery.com/123-circular-plot-circlize-package-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fully reproducible example of such a graph created from a weighted adjacency matrix:

```r
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)

set.seed(1)

adj <- matrix(rbinom(900, 1, 0.02) * runif(900, -1, 1), 30,
              dimnames = list(paste('node', 1:30), 
                              paste('node', 1:30)))

graph <- graph.adjacency(adj, weighted = TRUE)

ggraph(graph, layout = 'linear', circular = TRUE) + 
  geom_edge_arc(aes(color = weight, size = abs(weight))) + 
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name, angle = node_angle(x, y)), hjust = -0.5) +
  geom_node_point(shape = 21, size = 4, aes(fill = name)) +
  theme_graph() +
  scale_edge_color_gradientn(colours = c('red4', 'gold', 'green4')) +
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(-1.4, 1.4), ylim = c(-1.4, 1.4)) +
  guides(fill = guide_none())
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, I tried your code, but there is an error: ```Error in check.length(gparname) : 
  'gpar' element 'lwd' must not be length 0```, can you please let me know what is the problem? Thanks

Comment: You need to update ggraph @DanLi